# The 'man enc' command is not working

Tags: openssl

For my lab assignment I am told to run the command 'man enc' to learn how to encipher things using openssl. I installed openssl on my linux machine, and the command 'man openssl' works, but the command'man enc' returns 'No manual entry for enc'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> run the command 'man enc' to learn how to encipher things using openssl

You can find the latest documentation online. For `man enc`, its located at [`apps/enc`](http://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/apps/enc.html) man pages.

---

> ... but the command'man enc' returns 'No manual entry for enc'.

It sounds like OpenSSL's man pages are not on-path. You can place them on-path by adjusting the `MANPATH` environmental variable. See the [`manpath(5)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/manpath.5.html) man page.

If you performed a straight `Configure` and then `make` and `make install` cycle, you may need to ensure `MANPATH` includes `/usr/local/ssl/share/man`. The path `/usr/local/ssl/share/man` may be wrong (I don't install the man pages), but `make install` tells you wher they are being copied to.